# Common methods used to reduce op-amps white noise?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise

I am a beginner learning about op-amps and DSP.

If an op-amp has 1 nVpp of noise/sqrt(Hz), at 1 MHz sampling rate the noise is 1 uVpp. If the sampling rate is quadrupled to 4 MHz, by averaging 4 samples to create each new sample the noise is doubled as well to 2 uVpp. Apparently, there is no increase in signal quality or reduction of the white noise.

What are the methods I can look into to learn more about how op-amps noise is reduced?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> at 1 MHz sampling rate the noise is 1 uVpp.

**No!** The noise voltage observed over 1 MHz **bandwidth** has a **standard deviation** 1 µV.

1. Bandwidth \$\ne\$ Sample rate. That's an important distinction! If you oversample a signal, you can improve your SNR; if you don't filter your Opamp's noise and sample it with 1 MS/s, then you don't get the noise amplitude you get within a bandwidth of 1 MHz, but that of the bandwidth of your ADC. Which will probably be much much higher!
2. It's **not a peak-to-peak voltage** as noted by you with "Vpp". It's a voltages's standard deviation; so, that thing your RMS voltage approaches on average for a sufficiently long observation. Peaks can (and will) be much higher!

> If the sampling rate is quadrupled to 4 MHz, by averaging 4 samples to create each new sample the noise is doubled as well to 2 uVpp.

**No!**

Noise is modeled as independent (here). So, the sum of two noise samples has a **variance** that is the sum of the two individual variances. So, since your noise voltage has constant variance, you get *twice the variance*. Now, the variance is the square of the standard deviation, which hence grows by a factor of \$\sqrt2\$.

If you average four noise samples, i.e., do a \$\frac{N_1 + N_2+ N_3+N_4}{4}\$, you get four times the variance (from the sum) **divided by \$4^2=16\$** (because of the constant ¼), so you get actually \$\frac{4}{4^2}=\frac14\$ of the original noise variance, and \$\sqrt\frac{1}{4}=\frac12\$ of the original noise voltage standard deviation (expected RMS voltage).

> Apparently, there is no increase in signal quality or reduction of the white noise.

**No.**

Oversampling grows the noise variance linearly (as discussed above). But it grows the amplitude for correlated components (i.e., your signal of interest) quadratically (because if two random variables \$A = B\$, then \$A+B=2A\$, and thus \$\operatorname{Var}(A+B) = \operatorname{Var}(2\cdot A) = 2^2\operatorname{Var}(A)\$.)

Comment: While the peak noise voltage is theoretically unlimited, it's extremely unlikely to greatly exceed the standard deviation; typical measurements and definitions are around 6σ.

Comment: Sure, that's how normal distributions work. But the standard deviation is by definition smaller than the actually occurring peak. Otherwise, it couldn't be the std dev.

Comment: No, I mean they *specified* it in terms of nVpp/rtHz. Not by σ.  You can work with σ by applying such an assumption, but asking for clarification would be better.  It seems like you outright *doubt* that they read the parameter correctly (op-amps most often give RMS noise density; peak noise *in a bandwidth* is sometimes given though) -- which I agree seems likely -- but if this is the case, it should probably be noted/emphasized as such; that's all.

Comment: Thank you Marcus. Two follow-up questions. 1. If I am understanding it correctly Bandwidth = input frequency or the signal amplified by the op-amp, not the sampling rate. The Vrms/Vpp noise specified in op-amps data sheet is applicable for input frequency. An eg. for understanding purposes only: What if there are two active filters averaging the op-amps voltages over 1 second. Two op-amps/active filters running at 1 MHz and 4 MHz respectively, will the noise depend on input frequency only and not on the rate? Since no ADC is connected yet.

Comment: 2. Will the same be true for any thermal noise of the transducer connected to op-amps? electrode-skin interface has a thermal noise and forms a galvanic half-cell.

Comment: *If I am understanding it correctly Bandwidth = input frequency or the signal amplified by the op-amp, not the sampling rate.* Nope, bandwidth is bandwidth, not frequency just a frequency.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I meant to say, it seems op-amp noise is dependent on the input signal's frequency only. Not on the sampling rate of the ADC. Is that correct? If the input signal freq. is 100Hz and voltage noise density is given as 1 nV sqrt(Hz) then op-amp noise is 1 * sqrt(100) = 10 nV. It does not depend on sampling. Is this understanding correct? I understand that bandwidth is a separate concept.

Comment: No, it's not dependent. What matters for such noise is the system bandwidth, not frequency of the signal.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I had asked the same question here but got a different response. https://ez.analog.com/amplifiers/operational-amplifiers/f/q-a/572003/a-slight-confusion-regarding-a-fundamental-in-op-amps-there-is-no-sampling-so-hz-voltage-noise-density-given-in-data-sheets-is-applicable-for-the-frequency-of-the-voltages-being-amplified-by-it-or-is-it-for-sampling-rate-of-t

Comment: Gladion on that forum confuses a couple of things. He's honestly just wrong. The input signal doesn't change your amplifier's noise bandwidth. I find that super intuitive: whether I make a pure 220 Hz tone or a pure 2200 Hz tone doesn't change how much my amplifier makes noise, right. He also seems confused about "Gaussian"  (that's not the same as "white"), which describes how the random amplitude of noise is distributed for every moment individually, and not how noise power is distributed  in the spectrum.

Comment: I mean you do understand the difference between a system (like, a filter, or an amplifier) and a signal (like a 220 Hz tone or random noise), right? You also understand how a system can pass a bandwidth? If not, these would be things you want to look up.